# A question about spaces of continous function.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, sobolev-spaces, uniform-continuity

In Appendix A.3 of Evans's PDE(2rd edition), I find the definition of $C^k(\bar{U})$ is :
$$
C^k(\bar{U}) = \{u\in C^k(\bar{U}) | D^{\alpha}u \text{ is uniformly continous on bounded subsets of U, for all}\,\, |\alpha|\leq k\}
$$
where $U\subset \mathbf R^n$ is open.

However, in Adams's sobolev spaces Para 1.28, I find that he said
'''
We define the vector spaces $C^m(\bar{\Omega})$ to consist of all those $\phi\in C^{m}(\Omega)$ for which $D^{\alpha}(\phi)$ is bounded and uniformly continous on $\Omega$ for $0\leq |\alpha| \leq m$.
''' where $\Omega$ is a domain.

Are these two definitions equavalent? And why there are different definitons of $C^{m}(\bar{U})$?

Comment: I would think that $u(x) = sin(x^2)$ is in $C^0(\mathbb R)$ in the sense of Evans but not of Adams. These definitions are equivalent if the domain is bounded.